# Waiting for all coroutines with when_all

Tags: c++, seastar

```
    #include <seastar/core/app-template.hh>
    #include <seastar/core/coroutine.hh>
    #include <seastar/core/sleep.hh>
    #include <seastar/core/when_all.hh>

/*Here I want all the futures to execute*/
    seastar::future<> all_futures()
    {
        seastar::sleep(2s).then([]{std::cout << "2s\n";});
        seastar::sleep(1s).then([]{std::cout << "1s\n";});
        return seastar::sleep(3s).then([]{std::cout << "3s\n";});//CHANGE HERE TO VALUE < 2s
    }
    
    seastar::future<int> get_int()
    {
        std::cout << "Entering winter sleep\n";
        return seastar::sleep(5s).then([]{return 2;}); //CHANGE HERE TO VALUE < 3s
    }
    
    seastar::future<> f_sleeping() {
        std::cout << "Sleeping... " << std::flush;
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
//Here I want to wait for all the futures and only exit after all futures finished
        return when_all(all_futures(),get_int().then([](const int val){std::cout << "got: " << val << '\n'; })).discard_result();
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        app_template app;
    
        return app.run(argc, argv, [&app] {
            
            return f_sleeping();
        });
    }
```

When running the code as it is everything seems to work as intended. But try to change the waiting time in lines marked //CHANGE HERE TO VALUE
and suddenly not all futures are being waited for!!!
So the question is, how to wait for x number of futures?
Another question is, is this a bug in that library or is it simply C++ which at this stage becomes really old tech that cannot catch such problems during the compilation?
Yet, another question is, why does it compile at all. I've looked into the declaration of when_all and apparently it accepts pair of iterators. I do not in the code above, give any iter to that function and yet it compiles and runs. As is often the case with C++, not correctly, without giving as little as one single warning...

**EDIT|**
The error:

> error: could not convert ‘seastar::when_all(FutOrFuncs&& ...) [with
> FutOrFuncs = {seastar::future, seastar::future,
> seastar::future}]((* & std::moveseastar::future<&>(one)), (* &
> std::moveseastar::future<&>(three)))’ from
> ‘futurestd::tuple<seastar::future<void, seastar::future,
> seastar::future >>’ to ‘future’   172 |     return
> when_all(std::move(two), std::move(one), std::move(three));
> |            ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> |                    |
> |                    futurestd::tuple<seastar::future<void, seastar::future, seastar::future >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only returning one future out of `all_futures`, the first two are discarded. Having done that, there's no way of waiting for them, so if nothing else waits as long as they do, they might outlive `main`.

If you do want to wait for them, you need to have *something* wait for them.

```
seastar::future<> all_futures()
{
    auto two = seastar::sleep(2s).then([]{std::cout << "2s\n";});
    auto one = seastar::sleep(1s).then([]{std::cout << "1s\n";});
    auto three = seastar::sleep(3s).then([]{std::cout << "3s\n";});
    return when_all(std::move(two), std::move(one), std::move(three)).discard_result();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but...
a) doesn't compile (I'll post the actual error in OP):
b) The example I've provided is taken verbatim (the all_futures) from seastar tutorial page.

Comment: @DeborahC oh, it needs to explicitly discard the result

Comment: thank you. How did you, where from, you knew that the discard result needs to be used?

Comment: What about the fact that it did compile? I mean, surely if when_all requires pair of iters and is being given three futures, it shouldn't compile?

Comment: @DeborahC There are (at least) two (template) overloads of `when_all`, one that takes a pack of futures, and another that takes a pair of iterators to a sequence of futures. I could work it out from the error message, I was expecting there to be an implicit conversion to `future<>`, but it seems that library doesn't like implicit